# Prevent user for adding any script/jquery/sql queries in the description field

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to add some validation for the description field to check if the user has entered any scripting/js/jQuery/SQL query code rather than a genuine product description.

```
// Check for disallowed patterns (JavaScript, jQuery, and SQL)
$disallowedPatterns = array(
    '/\b(?:alert|confirm|prompt)\b\s*\([^;]*\)\s*;/i' => 'JavaScript code (script tag)',
    '/\b(?:alert|confirm|prompt)\s*\([^)]*(?<!["\']\s*;)\)\s*;/i' => 'JavaScript functions with parenthesis (alert, confirm, prompt)',
    '/\$\([^)]*\)\.?[a-z]+/i' => 'jQuery-related patterns',
    '/\b(?:select|insert|update|delete|union|where)\b/i' => 'SQL keywords'
);

$codeDetected = false;
foreach ($disallowedPatterns as $pattern => $description) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $params['propertydescription'])) {
        $codeDetected = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ($codeDetected) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid input. The description contains disallowed content: $description");
}
```

But somehow, this is not working 100% for me.

I want to know if I am choosing the right way or if any third-party library can check/prevent the same.

Comment: Why don't you use a library such as HTML Purifier to not only remove all malicious code (better known as XSS) but also make sure the HTML is correctly formed?

Comment: @KarlHill, but will it return that what content the user has written which is not allowed ?

Comment: Your code should already be safe against SQL, unless you're insert the user data directly into a SQL query unescaped, which you should never do anyway. You should always use prepared statements with placeholders, or in your case, you should be using CI's database library which handles it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on [XSS Filtering](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html?highlight=xss#xss-filtering) (`application/config/config.php`)

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

Or In validation like this `xss_clean`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
```

---

It will

- Escape characters like `<`, `>`, `"`, `'`, and `&` are converted into their HTML entities (like `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, `&#39;`, and `&amp;`)
- It removes or sanitizes input that contains potentially harmful scripts or tags `<script>`
- etc..

Comment: I have entered 

`Cleaned Input:   $("body").html("Test")
<script>alert("This is a malicious script!");</script>`


and I got the output
`Cleaned Input: $("body").html("Test") [removed]alert("This is a malicious script!");[removed]`

using `$cleanInput = $this->security->xss_clean($params['propertydescription']);`

Instead of expecting the content without knowing which code/text was removed

Answer (score -4):

You can use filter_var to detect a pattern match, here is my implementation

```php
$disallowedPatterns = array(
        '/\b(?:alert|confirm|prompt)\b\s*\([^;]*\)\s*;/i' => 'JavaScript code (script tag)',
        '/\b(?:alert|confirm|prompt)\s*\([^)]*(?<!["\']\s*;)\)\s*;/i' => 'JavaScript functions with parenthesis (alert, confirm, prompt)',
        '/\$\([^)]*\)\.?[a-z]+/i' => 'jQuery-related patterns',
        '/\b(?:select|insert|update|delete|union|where)\b/i' => 'SQL keywords'
    );

    // Sanitize and validate the input
    $params['propertydescription'] = filter_var($params['propertydescription'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (empty($params['propertydescription'])) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input. The description cannot be empty");
    }

    $codeDetected = false;
    foreach ($disallowedPatterns as $pattern => $description) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $params['propertydescription'])) {
            $codeDetected = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($codeDetected) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input. The description contains disallowed content: $description");
    }
```